How to update user email and be notified when email is verified?
I am using Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail: String), having reauthenticated the user (using Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: AuthCredential).
I want to be notified when the user has clicked on the link in the email sent to them and the email has been verified so that I can report that it's been successfully verified back to the user and so that I can dismiss the view automatically. It seems there's no built-in way to do this as far as I can tell.
I've tried using a Timer that repeatedly reloads the user and checks if the user's email is equal to the new email provided:
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.5, repeats: true) { timer in
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        
        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.email == email {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}

However, when the email is verified, the following error is thrown saying that the user's credential is no longer valid (likely due to the fact that the email has changed), reesulting in the user being signed out:

Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17021 "The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED, NSLocalizedDescription=The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.}

How can I be notified when the email is verified without signing out the user?
